# Entity Framework 6.1: CRUD on Child objects

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I populate a data grid with a list of objects that come from a repository like this:

```
   public static IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersForDataGrid()
    {
        IEnumerable<Order> query;
        using (RSDContext = new RSDContext())
        {
            query = context.Orders.Include(o=>o.OrderDetails).ToList();
        }
        return query;
    }
```

When I want to edit an order I pass the selected row to a new window like this:

```
 OrderEditWindow orderEdit = new OrderEditWindow();
        orderEdit.SelectedOrder = SelectedOrder;
        orderEdit.ShowDialog();
```

Here I set the DataContext of the Window to:

```
DataContext = SelectedOrder;
```

In this window I have another data grid that binds to `OrderDetails` collection property of `Order`. The problem is on CRUD operations on `OrderDetails`. For example, after I add a new orderDetail like this:

```
  private void AddProductDetailButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ValidateProductDetail())
            return;
        var _selectedProduct = ProductAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem as Product;
        var selectedProduct = ProductsRepository.GetProductById(_selectedProduct.ProductId);
        OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
        orderDetail.Price = selectedProduct.Price;
        orderDetail.ProductCode = selectedProduct.Code;
        orderDetail.ProductName = selectedProduct.Name;
        orderDetail.Quantity = int.Parse(QuantityNumericUpDown.Value.ToString());
        orderDetail.Um = selectedProduct.Um;
        orderDetail.Total = selectedProduct.Price * int.Parse(QuantityNumericUpDown.Value.ToString());
        orderDetail.Group = selectedProduct.Subgroup.Group.Name;
        orderDetail.Subgroup = selectedProduct.Subgroup.Name;
        orderDetail.SupplierName = selectedProduct.Supplier.Name;
        //orderDetail.Order=SelectedOrder;
        //orderDetail.OrderId = SelectedOrder.OrderId;
        SelectedOrder.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        ProductAutoCompleteBox.Text = string.Empty;
        QuantityNumericUpDown.Value = 1;
        ProductAutoCompleteBox.Focus();

    }
```

and then I call the update method from repository:

```
  public static void UpdateOrder(Order order)
    {
        using (RSDContext context = new RSDContext())
        {
            context.Orders.Attach(order);
            context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I get an error about OrderId. If i set manualy the navigation property and the id I don't get an error but changes dont get saved into db.

My `Order` model look like this:

```
 public  class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Order()
    {
        _OrderDetails = new ObservableCollection<OrderDetail>();
        _OrderDetails.CollectionChanged += _OrderDetails_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void _OrderDetails_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            AttachProductChangedEventHandler(e.NewItems.Cast<OrderDetail>());
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            CalcualteTotals();
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal CalculatedTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return OrderDetails.Sum(x => x.Total);
        }
    }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    private int _Number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return _Number; }
        set
        {
            _Number = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _Date;

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set
        {
            _Date = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    private bool _Canceled;

    public bool Canceled
    {
        get { return _Canceled; }
        set
        {
            _Canceled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Canceled");
        }
    }
    private string _ClientName;

    public string ClientName
    {
        get { return _ClientName; }
        set
        {
            _ClientName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClientName");
        }
    }
    private string _ClientPhone;

    public string ClientPhone
    {
        get { return _ClientPhone; }
        set
        {
            _ClientPhone = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClientPhone");
        }
    }

    private string _DeliveryAddress;

    public string DeliveryAddress
    {
        get { return _DeliveryAddress; }
        set
        {
            _DeliveryAddress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DeliveryAddress");
        }
    }

    private decimal _Transport;

    public decimal Transport
    {
        get { return _Transport; }
        set
        {
            _Transport = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Transport");
        }
    }

    private decimal _Total;

    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return _Total; }
        set
        {
            _Total = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }



    private ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> _OrderDetails;

    public virtual ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails
    {
        //get { return _OrderDetails ?? (_OrderDetails = new ObservableCollection<OrderDetail>()); }
        get
        {
            return _OrderDetails;
        }
        set
        {
            _OrderDetails = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("OrderDetails");
        }
    }
    private void AttachProductChangedEventHandler(IEnumerable<OrderDetail> orderDetails)
    {

        foreach (var p in orderDetails)
        {
            p.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "Quantity":
                    case "Price":
                    case "Total":
                        CalcualteTotals();
                        break;
                }
            };
        }

        CalcualteTotals();
    }

    public void CalcualteTotals()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CalculatedTotal");

    }
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And my OrderDetail model look like this:

```
 public class OrderDetail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }

    private int _ProductCode;
    public int ProductCode
    {
        get { return _ProductCode; }
        set
        {
            _ProductCode = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCode");
        }
    }

    private string _ProductName;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _ProductName; }
        set
        {
            _ProductName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    private string _Um;

    public string Um
    {
        get { return _Um; }
        set
        {
            _Um = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Um");
        }
    }

    private decimal _Price;

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _Price; }
        set
        {
            _Price = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Price");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");

        }
    }

    private int _Quantity;

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _Quantity; }
        set
        {
            _Quantity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");

        }
    }

    private string _SupplierName;

    public string SupplierName
    {
        get { return _SupplierName; }
        set
        {
            _SupplierName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SupplierName");
        }
    }

    private string _Subgroup;

    public string Subgroup
    {
        get { return _Subgroup; }
        set
        {
            _Subgroup = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Subgroup");
        }
    }

    private string _Group;

    public string Group
    {
        get { return _Group; }
        set
        {
            _Group = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Group");
        }
    }

    public decimal _Total;

    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return Quantity * Price; }
        set
        {
            _Total = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really trying to use some sort of unit of work and I don't understand how i'm supposed to apply CRUD on objects with child collections and keep the UI updated in the same time (by working in a `ObservableCollection` and using `Binding ClientPhone, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` my parent window is updated as I type)

**A final working solution:**

```
   using (RSDContext context = new RSDContext())
        {
            var details = order.OrderDetails;
            order.OrderDetails = null;
            List<int> OriginalOrderDetailsIds =
             context.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.OrderId == order.OrderId).Select(o => o.OrderDetailId).ToList();
            List<int> CurrentOrderDetailsIds = details.Select(o => o.OrderDetailId).ToList();
            List<int> DeletedOrderDetailsIds = OriginalOrderDetailsIds.Except(CurrentOrderDetailsIds).ToList();

            context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            foreach (var deletedOrderDetailId in DeletedOrderDetailsIds)
            {
                context.Entry(context.OrderDetails.Single(o => o.OrderDetailId == deletedOrderDetailId)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            foreach (OrderDetail detail in details)
            {
                // Add.
                if (detail.OrderDetailId == 0)
                {
                    detail.OrderId = order.OrderId;
                    context.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                // Update.
                else
                {
                    context.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in the wpf, but in the EF, you need to get the order from context that includes the details, then merge the order ui with order db

Comment: If I do that, it works but I loose the UI updating in real time.I know I can implement a pub/sub pattern (witch I have to learn first) but I'm hopping there is a solution because feels so natural to take an object and modify all aspect of it and then push it back to the db.

Comment: I think `push it back to the db` for child collection is not done by only changing the state of the parent object, you need to merge the child collection from ui and db

Comment: I will look into how I can do that. Thanks. *Maybe loop through all child's and insert/remove them manually. I will try that in the save method. I'm thinking that if I do this in the Collection Changed event I will break my unit of work mentality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this way for adding and updating the child, but not sure about deleted order details in the ui. If you don't want to get the order from entity, you need some kind of marking in the OrderDetail for deleted OrderDetail.

```
using (RSDContext context = new RSDContext())
{
    var details = order.OrderDetails;
    order.OrderDetails = null;

    context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (var detail in details)
    {
        if (detail.Id == 0)
        {
            // Adds.
            detail.OrderId = order.Id;
            context.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else if (detail.IsDeleted)
        // Adds new property called 'IsDeleted' 
        //  and add [NotMapped] attribute 
        //  then mark this property as true from the UI for deleted items.
        {
           // Deletes.
           context.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
           // Updates.
           context.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    order.OrderDetails = details;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank You. I think this is the best approach.  I would look into find how to know an entity was deleted

Comment: I think I need to manage my self the deletion code because now I use the Delete command and when I'm in this loop I can't see deleted objects. Thank You. *I'm thinking that I could make a compare with the object from db and delete them.

Comment: @andySF, you could add new property called `IsDeleted` and add `[NotMapped]` attribute, then mark it from the UI as true when the items is deleted (by subscribing collection changed event or delete button clicked event?), as my updated answer

Comment: I all ready did that.I set the IsDeleted=true, on collection change event but then i realized that it's useless because in the foreach loop I can't  iterate through deleted items because they are not there

Comment: okay, that makes sense in that case, I thought the changes from the UI will be applied by some kind of `Save` button, then store the deleted items in other collections (+ mark it as deleted), and re-adds to the collection before sending to the backend

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the question with a solution that work's for me.

Comment: You have +1 from me just because you had enough patience to read the whole story! ^_^