# New subentity will not save when parent entity is saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have a parent entity

`foo` which exists in the db, I have a property `bar` on this entity (One to many relation).

`Foo` is detached because its deserialized using WebApi, so I do this to `foo`

```
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);
```

Even If there is a new `bar` reference attached to it, it wont get saved, however it does work like this for another relation we have which is a Many to many relation. If I add a new entity to that collection it will be saved to its table and also a row is added to the relation table.

If I do `context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(foo.Bar);` before calling `context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);` it will save the new bar correctly to the bar table, but it wont add the correct barId to the foo table

**@Yuliam Chandra**

If i understand your answer correctly (I think you are mixing up bars and foos in your answer) this should work?

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.FooId = 524 //Existing foo;

foo.Bar = new Bar(); //Completely new bar    
db.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But it does not

Comment: How is the new bar being added to foo?  When you call context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo), is the foreign key set on bar?

Comment: Bar does not hold the foreign key, Foo is. Foo.BarId

Comment: So - in your 'One to many', you have One bar to many Foos?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, (Many to one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with disconnected objects needs extra code.

> If you are working with disconnected objects you must manually manage
>   the synchronization.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx)

If `Bar` is an existing entity you need to attach it first, so `Foo` will be added as `Bar's` children.

```
if (foo.Bar.Id != 0)
{
    context.Bars.Attach(foo.Bar);
    context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);
}
```

The example of above code is similar with `Course` (`Foo`) and `Department` (`Bar`) example in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

But if `Bar` is a new entity you just need to add `Foo`, then `Bar` will also be added.

```
else
{
    context.Foos.Add(foo);
}
```

Some other variety can be checked on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24886346/968303).

## update

Before explaining further, I'd like show identical code.

- `db.Set<T>().Add(instance)` equals to `db.Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Added;`
- `db.Set<T>().Attach(instance)` equals to `db.Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

The previous answer explained about two conditions.

- New Foo and existing Bar

  `context.Bars.Attach(foo.Bar);`

  `context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);`
- New Foo and new Bar

  `context.Foos.Add(foo);`

## Special Added

`Added` has special condition, once an entity is marked as `Added`. all the entities in the graph will be marked as `Added` too, even if any reference entity is an existing object in the database. If we have this code, Foo and Bar will be added.

```
var foo = new Foo (); // new foo
foo.Bar = new Bar { BarId = 123 }; // existing bar
db.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

To prevent that from happening, Bar needs to be attached first.

```
var foo = new Foo (); // new foo
foo.Bar = new Bar { BarId = 123 }; // existing bar
db.Set<Bar>().Attach(bar);
db.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Check [Julie Lerman article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) for more complete explanation.

> The reason it happens is that when you use the DbSet.Add method (that
>   is, Screencasts.Add), not only is the state of the root entity marked
>   “Added,” but everything in the graph that the context was not
>   previously aware of is marked Added as well. Even though the developer
>   may be aware that the Topic has an existing Id value, Entity Framework
>   honors its EntityState (Added) and creates an Insert database command
>   for the Topic, regardless of the existing Id.

## Adjust Explanation Based On Your Update

And your updated question is about existing Foo and new Bar. Using your code, the result will not add new Bar and existing Foo will not make a relationship with new Bar.

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.FooId = 524 //Existing foo;

foo.Bar = new Bar(); //Completely new bar    
db.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If we manually add the Bar together with `AddOrUpdate(foo)`, the result is still not as expected. The new Bar will be added, but Foo will not have relationship with the new Bar.

```
db.Bars.Add(foo.Bar);
db.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo);
```

The behavior of `AddOrUpdate` is inconsistent.

## Solution

> If you are working with disconnected objects you must manually manage
>   the synchronization.

This code should work in all conditions.

- New Foo and New Bar
- New Foo and Existing Bar
- Existing Foo and New Bar
- Existing Foo and Existing Bar

This code depends on the id (id = 0 is a new entity).

```
db.Entry(foo).State = 
       foo.FooId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
if (foo.Bar != null)
{
    db.Entry(foo.Bar).State = 
       foo.Bar.BarId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                                                             ^^^
    // If you don't want to change the Bar while creating a relationship between
    // Foo and with existing Bar, you can change 
    // `EntityState.Modified` with `EntityState.Unchanged`
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Related to `AddOrUpdate`, I think there is an open issue that can be found [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128).

Comment: Hmm, think I tried this. Will try more over the weekend and let you know

Comment: @Anders, I updated the answer to explain further with your update

Comment: Sounds like nHibernate is still ahead of EF :D Will try this and get back to you, thanks for all your help!

Comment: It works, thanks! It feels like it shouldn't need to be this complicated to work with detached entities. Must be a very common scenario in CRUD systems that you seralize / deserliaze entities from client

Comment: @Anders, yup, sadly currently EF doesn't have extension method that handles disconnected objects