# Entity Framework One-To-Many issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I use Entity Framework in my project. I stuck in some trouble.

I have two classes. Here are they:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Requisites { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Workers { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have repo. So when I create a new user and I want to add this user to company.
How should I implement that? I have two ways:

1. `user.Company = company;`
2. `company.Workers.Add(user);`

Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `company` is already attached to the context.

Either

```
var company = db.Set<Company>().Find(companyId);
```

or

```
db.Set<Company>().Attach(company);
```

**user.Company = company;**

In the first case, if you only do that. The user will not be added to the database, you need to have this too.

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
```

or

```
db.Set<User>().Add(user);
```

Then user will be added and will have relationship with company.

**company.Workers.Add(user);**

This one only should be okay, the user will be added and have relationship with company. But be careful if `Workers` is null, you need to instantiate it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if user and company already exist. Then which way is better to assign user to company (create relationship between them)?

Comment: yes if both of them already exists, I think it's better to use assignment, it will also remove the user from previous assigned company, but remember that the user must be in [Modified State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and company must be attached or in the [Unchanged State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), check my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25080866/968303)

Comment: OK! How about if I want to unbind worker from a company. Which is better? company.Workers.Remove(worker); or worker.Company = null; ? If i use 1st way, it will remove only relation or it will delete worker from db as well?